# "No such file or directory" error in ubuntu 12.04 eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

everybody, I'm a fresh in c++, when I try to build a project and a error happens in the follow codes:

```cpp
#ifndef GAMEPLAYEREX_H_
#define GAMEPLAYEREX_H_

#include "GamePlayer.h"


class GamePlayerEx : virtual public GamePlayer
{
public:
    GamePlayerEx(int = 0);
    virtual ~GamePlayerEx(void);
......
```

and the error information is:

```
In file included from ../GameEngine/GameMoudle/GamePlayerEx.cpp:8:0:
../GameEngine/GameMoudle/GamePlayerEx.h:11:24: fatal error: GamePlayer.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

my project directory is like the follow image, I don't wanner use `#include "../GamePlayer.h"`.

so, somebody know how to configure in project and let it work? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably meant to name your folder **GameModule**, not Game*Moudle*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gcc (or most other command line compilers), you can set the include path to include arbitrary directories, such as with:

```
gcc -I.. myfile.cpp
```

This will search those directories for the include files.

If you're using an IDE, there'll be IDE or project settings you can modify. For example, [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) for Eclipse Galileo CDT shows how to set up an include path for a given project.